# 「自分」の使い方を詳しく説明していただけませんか。

Tags: usage

こんにちは！質問があります。

「私の意見を述べました」と「自分の意見を述べました」はどう違いますか。

そして、「自分」の詳しい使い方を説明していただけませんか。

よろしくおねがいします！

Answer (score 1):

I think 私 is formal and　自分 is a little chatty. So 私 is used in business but 自分 is less used there.

自分 is often used at Japanese sport desk in school. And it is used as second person in Osaka.

The detail is written here. https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E4%BA%BA%E7%A7%B0%E4%BB%A3%E5%90%8D%E8%A9%9E